# Why Java's String is not assignable from Comparable interface

Tags: java, reflection

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) says that `String` implements `Comparable<String>`

But, the following code returns `false`:

```
String.class.isAssignableFrom(Comparable.class)
```

How to check if some class implements given interface?

Comment: instanceof would help there

Comment: I have Class object not object itself.

Comment: You should read the JavaDoc of [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-), then you would know, that you switched object and parameter. It should be `Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what [`isAssignableFrom(cls)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) operates on. Quoting the Javadoc:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.

This means that when you are checking

```
String.class.isAssignableFrom(Comparable.class)
```

you are in fact checking if the `String` class is a super-class of the `Comparable` class, not the other way around. You should check:

```
Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. :D Nice timing :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to invert object and parameter.
Instead of

```
String.class.isAssignableFrom(Comparable.class)
```

You have to use

```
Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class)
```

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by **this Class object**
>   **is** either the same as, or is **a superclass or superinterface of**, the
>   class or interface represented by the specified Class **parameter**. It
>   returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.